# How do I avoid "pure virtual function call" errors when programming Adobe Illustrator via WIN32COM with Python?

Tags: python, win32com, adobe-illustrator

While writing python (3.12.2) code to interact with Adobe Illustrator via WIN32COM (Windows 10), I sometimes crash Illustrator with "pure virtual function call" errors.

Here is an example line of code that causes such a crash:

```
font_size = text_frame.TextRange.CharacterAttributes.Size
```

The mere act of trying to access the Size property triggers the crash. However, these two lines of semantically-equivalent code manage to avoid any crashing:

```
text_range = text_frame.TextRange
font_size = text_range.CharacterAttributes.Size
```

I'm hoping someone who knows the intricacies of WIN32COM programming can take me on a medium-depth dive into the technical guts of interacting with COM objects and perhaps explain why breaking up the access chain into two parts makes the code work. I'd like to be able to anticipate when this will happen so I can write working code without having to stumble into this minefield every time I try to access something new from the Illustrator object model.

The full exception traceback is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\John\PycharmProjects\Adobe API\Short Grain 500 Hex Coordinates.py", line 83, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\John\PycharmProjects\Adobe API\Short Grain 500 Hex Coordinates.py", line 21, in main
    original = OriginalTextInfo(item)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\John\PycharmProjects\Adobe API\hex_coord.py", line 10, in __init__
    self.font_size = item.TextRange.CharacterAttributes.Size
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\John\PycharmProjects\venv\Lib\site-packages\win32com\client\__init__.py", line 585, in __getattr__
    return self._ApplyTypes_(*args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\John\PycharmProjects\venv\Lib\site-packages\win32com\client\__init__.py", line 574, in _ApplyTypes_
    self._oleobj_.InvokeTypes(dispid, 0, wFlags, retType, argTypes, *args),
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147023170, 'The remote procedure call failed.', None, None)
```

Comment: I don't know exactly. Just a guess. The `TextRange` is an element of the collection `TextRanges`. Perhaps you have to use `text_frame.TextRanges(0).CharacterAttributes.Size`. But it doesn't explain why the `text_range = text_frame.TextRange` works fine. I'd say there should be `text_range = text_frame.TextRanges(0)`. (Probably there should be square brackets `[]` instead of the plain `()`)

Comment: Or may be `text_frame.TextRanges.Item(0).CharacterAttributes.Size`. As a guess.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: When opening Illustrator with `win32com.client.EnsureDispatch()`, the Adobe Illustrator type library is also loaded so that full object definitions are known to Python. When that type library has been loaded, collection objects like `TextRanges` don't support `[]` indexing, only access with `()`, and by default access is 1-based rather than 0-based. As an aside, when coding WIN32COM with VBScript, full access chains don't cause this kind of crashing. It must have something to do with the way the `win32com` package is implemented for Python?

Comment: Can we see the full error text? At a guess, the `TextRange` property returns an abstract base class interface, which does not implement the `CharacterAttribute` property (which might explain the "pure virtual function call" error).  By splitting up the calls, `text_range` is assigned to an IDispatch interface which can then get the `CharacterAttribute` via a derived class implementation. Checking the type of `text_range` may give some clues. It may be that an explicit cast of the interface is needed if using `EnsureDispatch()` rather than `Dispatch()` to create the object.

Comment: I've added the full exception traceback to my original post.